# How to implement the code on the peripheral on the arduino

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

If I want to connect to peripheral (Arduino) from my central (Iphone) do I have to structure the data in the arduino as a services and characteristics? I can implement the code on iphone ( using Core Bluetooth ) but how can i implement the code on peripheral side at the arduino ? It don't use Objective-C ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect a low energy bluetooth shield (BLE Shield) to your Arduino. Then you can pass data to BLE shield from the Arduino. Of course you will have to use C language to program the Arduino. Following link will guide you to do it, It has services and characteristics UUID's, sample project for iOS and arduino too.

[Red Bear Lab BLE sheild](http://redbearlab.com/bleshield/)

Hope this will help

Comment: thanks, now i can keep learning with your infomation!One more question, Can i define my own services and characteristics with my arduino and that BLE Shield!

Comment: Generally you can't. But you can do it if you update the firmware of Bluetooth shield. It has a firmware called biscuit. You can find the code here.(https://github.com/RedBearLab/Biscuit)

Comment: you will get some knowledge from this too (https://redbearlab.zendesk.com/entries/23378272-How-to-compile-my-own-firmware-for-BLE-Mini-)